# "Get" results of PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am getting warm with post PostGIS. 
I am working in the Command Line. What I am wondering is how do I "get" the results of PostGIS.

So imagine I have this

```
select name, neighname from neighborhoods where ST_Intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(586781.701577724 4504202.15314339,586863.51964484 4504215.9881701)', 26918));
```

That will prompt me something like this in the command line

```
    name    | neighname
------------+----------
   Mainst   | West Vill
         (1 row)
```

So far, so good. But how would I proceed working with this selection?

Can I somehow save that as a new shape?

Can I get the results into QGIS without the step of saving it as a shape (if that is possible)?

How can I proceed working with that selection in PostGIS?

Comment: "What can I do next with GIS?" is an unbounded question with infinite potential answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a table or a view from it:

```
 CREATE TABLE 
my_selection 
  AS SELECT
name, neighname 
  FROM 
neighborhoods 
  WHERE 
ST_Intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(586781.701577724 4504202.15314339,586863.51964484 4504215.9881701)', 26918));`
```

Although if you want it in QGIS you will also want to select the geometry so:

```
  CREATE TABLE 
 my_selection 
   AS SELECT 
 name, neighname, geom
   FROM 
 neighborhoods
   WHERE 
  ST_Intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(586781.701577724 4504202.15314339,586863.51964484 4504215.9881701)', 26918));`
```

You can add in PostGIS data directly into QGIS, that is what QGIS was built for. In QGIS Layer>Add Layer>Add PostGIS Layers...

Comment: And then with some sort of a Plug In I can import the table into QGIS?

Comment: You can add in PostGIS data directly into QGIS, that is what QGIS was build for. In QGIS Layer>Add Layer>Add PostGIS Layers...

Comment: There is an inbuilt function (elephant icon) called add postgis layers. Only need to do just set up the database connection